# PHP: Creating successful/unsuccessful login logs with database

Tags: php, mysql, logging

Hi I'm a basic PHP and MySql user. I have researched on the internet for hours but came without a conclusion.

What I'm trying to do is store logs in a database table that stores information if a user had a successful login or not. The table will store username, password, login time and if a the login was successful or not.

I have an idea of how I'll be able to do it. I'm planning to use Sessions, if example a session was started then the login was successful else the login was not successful. I'm not sure if this will work or no.

Can someone give me some hints on how I can achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would not store logs in a database. It is much simpler and faster to log using a text file. So you can use logrotate, logstash and all the log tools.

And storing the password is a huge security hole.

Comment: it's part of a stupid assignment and requires me to store logs on a database :/

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to storage password?

My solution:
Logs DB structure:

- id (int, autoincrement)
- login (varchar)
- time (date)
- success (tinyint(1))

When user execute login script and provided login and password are correct, you save requested data with success=1, when they are not, You save it with success=0.

Comment: Hmm seems like a good idea. I'll try that and come back to you! Thanks